# Pressing ''1'' in VS Code toggles whitespace indicators instead of inserting the character "1" into the editor. Why?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard

The button "1" in my laptop is working fine, when I press it in any other application other than VS Code, it works, but in VS Code, it doesn't work as I expect. It toggles the visibility of whitespace indicators instead of inserting the character "1" into the editor.

The number keys on my laptop keyboard are on the top row: <kbd>1234567890-=)</kbd>

[image: this photo explains the problem]

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation I can think of for this is that you have changed your keyboard shortcuts and that if you look in your keybindings.json file (use the `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)), you will see something along the lines of this:

```json
{
    "key": "1",
    "command": "editor.action.toggleRenderWhitespace"
}
```

If that's not the case, then either it's due to an extension, in which case you can figure out which one it is by doing an [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect), or it's something else related to keyboard issues, in which case I'd suggest that you go through the standard [keyboard troubleshooting steps](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues) (though given that your <kbd>1</kbd> key works as expected in other applications, I think this is less probably the cause).

Comment: it was the first solution, i must have mistakenly changed the setting, problem is solved. Thank you and appreciated @starball